# Creating shortcut in android and passing data while launching

Tags: android

My app maintains different clients data. For seeing each client data single activity is launched each time and depending on the bundle it shows particular client's data.
Now, I want to create a shortcut on homescreen for any client So that, only that client data could be directly seen after clicking the shortcut. But My problem is **how to give the extra data to activity while we click on shortcut** So that, I could show that particular client data.
Here is the code:

```
private void addShortcut() {
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

Intent addIntent = new Intent();
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "HelloWorldShortcut");
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
        Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),
                R.drawable.ic_launcher));

addIntent
        .setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

From what you've stated above, I think your best solution is going to involve persisting that user data, and then calling for it onCreate.

Here are some options available to you for saving the user data: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: But how will I discriminate that this shortcut is for this user and that shortcut is for that user. Since, on shortcut click I am unable to get any specific information from each shortcut.